# Getting pixel color at given position with p5js in vue

Tags: vue.js, p5.js

I am currently using p5.js in vue.
To get it running, I followed the steps described in [p5.js and vue - create a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852082/p5-js-and-vue-create-a-canvas/61855707#61855707).

This works perfectly fine, I am however stuck when it comes to using some functions provided by p5.
With this setup, how can I (e.g.) use the `get` function when trying to get the pixel at a given location. `b.img.get()` doesn't work. In a "normal" instance i could just skip the `b.`, but in vue I have to use it (as far as I understand)

```js
import * as P5 from 'p5';

export default {
  name: "Pixelation",
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      let w = document.getElementById("pixel").offsetWidth;
      let h = document.getElementById("pixel").offsetHeight;

      const sketch = b => {

        let img;
        let rad;

        b.preload = () => {
          img = b.loadImage(require('@/assets/tankman.png'));
        }

        b.setup = () => {
          b.createCanvas(w, h);
          b.image(img, 0, 0, w, h);
          rad = 30;
        }


        b.draw = () => {
          for(let i = 0; i < w; i += rad) {
            for (let j = Math.round(h / rad); j < h; h += rad) {
               b.fill(b.img.get(i, b.max(j, 0)));
               b.circle(i, j, rad);
            }
          }
        };
      }

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      let canvas = new P5(sketch, 'top');
    })
  }
}
```

```css
#pixel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="pixel"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at _.b.draw (Pixelation.vue?7872:34)
    at _.n.default.redraw (p5.min.js?3425:3)
    at _draw (p5.min.js?3425:3)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just massively misunderstood the way the b. has to be used.

When loading an image with `b.loadImage(require('@/assets/tankman.png'))` and assigning it to a variabel, all desired functions that are provided by p5 can be used by using
`variable.function()`, since `variabel` already includes the p5 functionality